# Need Millisecond Accuracy in DateTime in DetailsView c# How to Access Data directly in Details View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, detailsview, accessor

So I have been browsing stack overflow and MSDN and cannot find a control (or make sense of the ones I have) to access the data directly of a detailsview. I'm in C# using a .Net WebApplication.

I think what I am looking for is the equivalent in gridview is row.Cells[1].Value can anybody help with the accessor to the DetailsView cells?

What I am trying to do is to access the exact data values I have bound to the DetailsView1
.Text is sufficient for all the numbers and string (only two shown for example) but not for the timestamp MTTS (a datetime) as it lost the milliseconds and the code (SQL query) I use after it cannot find the correct values in the db without the milliseconds. Will I also need to change the way I have bound the data, or some setting to give the bound data millisecond accuracy?

Code example:

```
    Decimal RUN_ID = 0;
    DateTime MTTS = new DateTime();

    foreach(DetailsViewRow row in DetailsView1.Rows)            
    {                
            switch(row.Cells[0].Text)
            {

                case "RUN_ID":
                    RUN_ID = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);
                    break;
                case "MTTS":
                    MTTS = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[1].ToString());                       
                    break;

           }

   }
```

I have tried

```
   row.Cells[1].ID = "MTTS";
   MTTS = (DateTime)((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["MTTS"];
```

But it does not recognize the MTTS and I am not sure how to set the parameter I have tried a few different things already with no success.

Comment: If you can change the way data are bound, then perhaps you can do supply ms separately. If you need underlying data, then consider do not use *view* to get them, make a method to get what you need from data directly. This way you can get `DateTime` and format it as you like.

Comment: This was the workaround I used, new user here how do I give you credit? I wrote a new sql conn to get the timestamp and saved it to a DateTime. If anyone has a painless solution it would be good to know

Comment: You could share your solution and mark it as answer. This way others who have the same problem would have solution *on a plate* =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround was messy, essentially I rebuilt the query that gathered the data to the GridView and then I made a function to grab the MTTS directly using LinQ and the parameteres from inside the GridView which  assigns the MTTS as a DateTime.

This was in my opinion a bad way of doing things but it worked. I would prefer a better solution.

```
    MTTS = GetMTTS(JOB_PLAN, JOB_NAME,JOB_NAME_ID,RUN_ID,JOB_STATUS);

    public DateTime GetMTTS(string JOB_PLAN, string JOB_NAME, string JOB_NAME_ID, Decimal RUN_ID, string JOB_STATUS){

        string myEnvName = XXX;
        TableName = XXX.ToString();
        ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myEnvName].ToString();

        string thisRUN_ID = RUN_ID.ToString();
        cmdText = @"SELECT MTTS FROM " + TableName + 
            " WHERE JOB_PLAN = '" + JOB_PLAN + "'"
            + " AND JOB_NAME = '" + JOB_NAME + "'"
            + " AND JOB_NAME_ID = '" + JOB_NAME_ID + "'"
            + " AND RUN_ID = '" + thisRUN_ID + "'"
            + " AND JOB_STATUS = '" + JOB_STATUS + "'";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();           
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand SQLcc = new SqlCommand(cmdText,conn);
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = SQLcc.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MTTS = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                }        
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }                
        }
        return MTTS;
    }
```